# Trying to use selenium to enter things into a textbox on a website

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I've looked around and I tried using different versions of `WebElement userid = driver.findElement(By.xpath` and `WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.id("email"));` but they return a syntax error when I try to use them.

For reference, [this is the textbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0uNe.png) I want to type in

and [this is the html xpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuTTw.png) I found from using inspect element on that box.

This is my first time using python & selenium so please be easy on me :)

EDIT: I'm now on the dropdown menu part of this script and I don't know how to use the select function

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1J1nZ.png)

Comment: Hi @KwabenaOsei welcome to Stackoverflow! It would be very helpful if you could provide the errors you see when using each line in addition to larger snippets of your code instead of one line. In addition to that, if you could provide a link to the html you are trying to xpath it would help a lot (if it's public of course).

Comment: No worries! Feel free to update your original post as you go to provide more details into what is happening

Comment: use //input[@[placeholder="Email"] as  the xpath to locate element and make sure that  you wait for the visibility of element before sending keys to it.
Or better wait for the element to be interactable

Answer (score 0):

So, based on your `HTML` code, I think that the `xpath` that you need is this

```
//div[@data-section='customer-information']//input[@id='checkout_email']
```

Based on this `xpath`, you could write your code as such

```
sampleEmail = "MySampleEmail@Email.com"
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@data-section='customer-information']//input[@id='checkout_email']").send_keys(sampleEmail)

if(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@data-section='customer-information']//input[@id='checkout_email']").get_attribute('value').__len__() != sampleEmail.__len__()):
    raise Exception(f'Failed to populate our e-mail textbox with our value: {sampleEmail}')
```

Comment: Okay, so when I do this is it supposed to input my email that I have put in the sampleEmail? I'm trying to automate a text field for context.

Comment: @KwabenaOsei - Correct. `sampleEmail` is just a `variable`. I could have named it: `PythonIsTheBestScriptingLanguage` if I had wanted to. The goal is that `sampleEmail` is our `variable name` that holds our `string` or `text`. Once the `driver` finds our `WebElement` using the provided `xpath`, it will use the `send_keys()` method to type our email into the `textbox`.

Comment: okay so when I filled the string with my personal email, the textbox hasn't been updated though I think its because I made errors before. Also, would I be able to use that code for the other textboxes or would each box be different from the others?

Comment: @KwabenaOsei - Depends. If you have multiple textboxes under the `//div[@data-section='customer-information']`  `xpath` then you can follow a similar pattern. The way to find this out is by following these steps. #1 - Navigate to the Website that you need help with.  #2 - Open Chrome Dev Tools using F12.  #3 - Navigate to the `Elements` Tab.  #4 - Press `CTRL + F` to open the Find Search.  #5 - Enter the `xpath` and see if there are any other elements inside of that `div`

Answer (score 0):

To wait for an input tag with class field__input to be able to load in and send keys to it

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.field__input"))).send_keys("ANYTHING")
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: how would I be able to complete the following textboxes on the website from this code you've sent? (https://i.imgur.com/SbYR4rK.png)

Comment: Inspect each element and use their ids, or class and when it comes to the dropdown depending if it's using options you can use Select.

Comment: okay so I found the box that corresponds with the id and from this picture 
https://i.imgur.com/XRTPq7M.png  

 I used the id "checkout_shipping_address_first_name". So I did this


WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "checkout_shipping_address_first_name"))).send_keys("Kwabena"). But I don't think it works because I get this error https://i.imgur.com/Mt2JCyT.png

Comment: use By.ID instead of the CSS_SELECTOR

Comment: okay that helped and I managed to do many of the textboxes. I'm not stuck on the dropdown part, but I do remember you said something about using "select"?

Comment: sorry I am stuck on the dropdown part*